# Show that Statistic is complete

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Given $X_1,...,X_n$ iid. random variables which follow a $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ distribution. I already proved that 
$T:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\sigma^2$. Since, I want to apply the Lehmann-Scheffe Lemma, I have further to show that $T$ is complete, meaning that $\mathbb{E}_{\sigma^2}[g(T)]=0\Rightarrow g(T)=0$ for any measurable function $g$.

However, I am unable to do this, as I don't know how $T$ is distributed. Also there is a theorem which states that in exponential families the statistic is complete if the parameter space contains an open neighbourhood about the origin, but this is clearly not applicable since $\sigma^2\in (0,\infty)$. I would appreciate a little hint.

Comment: $T$ is minimal sufficient for $\sigma^2$ assuming $\mu$ is known and in this case $nT/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2_n$. What you said about the exponential family is not true in general. This is very much a member of exponential family.

Comment: That is a good hint. I have read, that I don't need the restriction that the neighbourhood is about the origin, just open suffices. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, sometimes open subset of $\mathbb R$ is mentioned for one-parameter families.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Ok, I solved it with the open set theorem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove the completeness directly as well without using the exponential family result.

A minimal sufficient statistic for $\sigma^2$ when $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\mu$ known is $$Z=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)^2$$

Since $Z/\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_n$, pdf of $Z$ is $$f_Z(z)=ce^{-z/2\sigma^2}z^{n/2-1}1_{z>0}\,,$$

where $c=c(n,\sigma^2)$ is such that $\displaystyle\int f_Z(z)\,dz=1$.

Now $\mathbb E_{\sigma^2}[g(Z)]=0$ for all $\sigma^2$ implies

$$\int_0^\infty g(z)e^{-z/2\sigma^2}z^{n/2-1}\,dz=0\quad,\forall\, \sigma^2$$

This is a [one-sided Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition) of $g(z)z^{n/2-1}$ and by property of integral transforms, you have $$g(z)z^{n/2-1}=0\,\,,\text{ a.e.}$$

Thus implying $$g(z)=0\,\,,\text{ a.e.}$$

So $\mathbb E_{\sigma^2}[g(Z)]=0$ for all $\sigma^2$ implies $g(Z)=0$ almost everywhere for any measurable function $g$.

Hence the family of distributions is complete.

Comment: A very nice alternative approach! Which property do of the integral transform do you mean exactly?

Comment: That if the integral transform of a function is zero, then that function is itself zero.

Comment: Actually, this proof can be generalized to the full-rank exponential family. For $X$ from an exponential family, $E_{\eta}g(x)=\int g(x)\exp(t(X)\eta)\mu(dx)$ thus $E_{\eta}g(x)$ is simply a Laplace transformation of $g(x)$.