# Show that the statistic $T(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$ is complete.

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid random sample form $N(\theta,c\theta)$, where $c$ is a known constant.
Show that the statistic $T(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2$ is complete.

In other words I have to show that if $$E[g(T)]=0\quad \Longrightarrow \quad g(T)=0 \quad \forall t$$

I'm kind of stuck with the distribution of $T$ because $x_i^2$ isn´t a gaussian distribution. Any suggestions on how to approach this problem would be great!

Comment: What is $g$? An arbitrary function?

Comment: @gt6989b - It is any function with $E[g(T)]=0$.  The question is about showing that has to be a particular function

Comment: $\sum \left(\frac{x_i-\theta}{\sqrt{c \theta}}\right)^2$ has a chi-squared distribution.

Comment: Follow similar steps as the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3443395/show-that-statistic-is-complete?rq=1) to show $T$ is complete.

Answer (score 1):

This is Proposition 2.1 on page 110 in [Jun Shao]Mathematical Statistics(2nd edition).